# How to implement a lookup picker with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement a lookup in a web application
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Creating a Dog and picking the owner :)
[image]

The intent is to click a button that opens a dialog box that has a view inside with a list. When the user clicks a button 'Associate' the data for that row is passed to the 'outter' view and it populates some controls with the picked data. I'm trying to achieve this with custom events with 'on' and 'trigger' from jquery.

Here is my approach:
Create Dog / Outter view:

```
...
<div id="dialogOwnerPicker" title="Pick the Owner" style="overflow: hidden;">

        </div>

<input type="button" id="dialogOpener" value="Pick" />
...

<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#dialogOwnerPicker").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 350,
            width: 530,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("<-- people view url -->");
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $("#dialogOwnerPicker").dialog().dialog('close');
            }

        });


        $("#dialogOwnerPicker").on("Associate", function (event, arg) {

            //do something with arg like populating controls or anything else
        });

        $("#dialogOpener").click(function () {
            $("#dialogOwnerPicker").dialog("open");
        });



    });

</script>
```

People / Inside dialog View:

```
...
 <input type="button" value="Associate" onclick="ClickButton('@item.Name')"/>

...
<script>


    function ClickButton(arg) {
        $("#dialogOwnerPicker").trigger("Associate", arg);

    }
</script>
```

Now, this doesn't work. Am I missing something or this is just not possible to do?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this bit:

```
$("#dialogOwnerPicker").on("Associate", function (event, arg) {

});
```

The first argument is the event, so your saying `on Associate` which js doesn't know what "Associate" is.

Rather you should say "on clicking the associate button..."

```
$("#associate_button_id").on('click', function (event, arg) {
    // Do something    
});
```

There is also a `click` function in jQuery so you can simply say

```
$("#associate_button_id").click(function (event, arg) {
    // Do something    
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to keep the inner view the most indepent possible from the outer view so it can be reusable. I just want the inner div to pass data out and make the outer div responsible from doing whatever it want to do with that data, from populating a control or showing an alert or whatever...